# How can I handle enormously large numbers in Java?

Tags: java, largenumber

I'm writing a program for my competitive programming class's homework and I can't get over one problem. This problem requires you to calculate all permutations of a certain string based on certain condition and my program does that. However, the problem is when the input is a really large string, it can be up to 10^6.

Solution to the problem is 2^result, where result depends on length of input string, so for 10^6 it can be up to 5*10^5. Solution must be given in form of: result % (10^9 + 7).

I've tried putting solution into a BigInteger, it runs out of heap space. I've tried working with doubles, it overflows. Is there something I'm missing or is there a way to deal with this? Thank you.

Here are some attempts:

```
System.out.println((int) (Math.pow(2, counter) % (1e9 + 7)));
//it prints out 0, probably due to overflow?

DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#");
System.out.println(df.format(Math.pow(2, counter) % (1e9 + 7)));
//prints out �
```

Comment: Have you looked at [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html)?

Comment: I've tried BigInteger, it runs out of heap space. Haven't tried BigDecimal, will try it now, thanks.

Comment: Your homework is to implement [modular exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation). BigInteger already implements it as [modPow](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#modPow(java.math.BigInteger,%20java.math.BigInteger)). You're not supposed to fully calculate the exponent, and then take the remainder.

Comment: I can't fully understand your question, because I can't tell when you're talking about a value, vs. when you're talking about the size of a value. For example: when you say the solution can be up to 5*10^5 -- that's actually not a very big number (it's just 500,000). Do you really mean that the solution can have up to 5*10^5 *digits*? (And, so on elsewhere in your question.)

Comment: @thatotherguy thanks a lot, it's exactly what I've been looking for. Never heard of modular exponentation before, I've implemented now and it's working. You can post your comment as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to handle enormously large numbers to do this.

The assignment intends for you to implement [modular exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation). BigInteger already implements it as [modPow](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#modPow(java.math.BigInteger,%20java.math.BigInteger)). It allows you to calculate `(b^e) % c` without having to deal with numbers significantly larger than `c`.

Here's Wikipedia's pseudo-code for remainder after exponentiation through repeated squaring:

```
function modular_pow(base, exponent, modulus)
    if modulus = 1 then return 0
    Assert :: (modulus - 1) * (modulus - 1) does not overflow base
    result := 1
    base := base mod modulus
    while exponent > 0
        if (exponent mod 2 == 1):
           result := (result * base) mod modulus
        exponent := exponent >> 1
        base := (base * base) mod modulus
    return result
```